# Why does jmeter dashboard formats response assertion error wrongly?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

JMeter dashboard shows error in a weird format, see below.

[image]

The response is correct, the majority of requests are succesfull.

Is there anything I should tweak?

Here is the response assertion:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
It seems to be some sort of diff, shows the same in view results: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "weird" format is defined in the [ResponseAssertion source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/ResponseAssertion.java#L505) and there is no easy way of amending it without changing the file and [recompiling JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)

Other options are:

1. Use "Custom failure message" section at the bottom of the Response Assertion:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Or switch to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) where you can implement whatever custom assertion logic and response message you want

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri! Is is possible to use the received value in the custom message?

Comment: You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like `${__groovy(prev.getResponseDataAsString(),)}` to get the parent sampler response data  where `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), check out JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on JMeter API shortcuts available for JSR223 Test Elements